# How to profile TYPO3 Back-End "List" module?

Tags: php, performance, profiling, typo3

I'm have latency problems in TYPO3 Back-End in mode List.

I've checked in TYPO3 repository, but it looks, what existing extensions oriented Fron-End only :

- http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typo3profiler
- http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/php_profiler

If there are some tools to analyze code performance in TYPO3 Back-End ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use XHProf, see e.g. this article: buzz.typo3.org/people/steffen-gebert/article/profiling-typo3-with-xhprof/

Comment: Yes, it's a good solution, I'm already thought about it. In my case it's some problematic, because PHP is working in FCGI mode, so I couldn't define php-value in .htacess. And as it's shared development machine, if I will active XHProf inclusions for all the instances, it will make development impossible for other developers.  The problem is what there are multiple entry points in TYPO3 BE, and   inclusion directly in mod.php doesn't worked with XHProf.

Comment: At least all the core modules are using the module dispatcher, so for them there's a central entry point. You could also trigger XHProf based on a cookie after adding your custom script as `auto_prepend_file`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the advice about condition on cookie. After multiple tests I could confirm, what XHPROF is the most performant and easy to use solution for TYPO3 profiling (after it's in place :P). And it gives great statistics. During this task also I tried xdebug, zend_debugger, apd.